# How to make a text in font/weight style bold in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need change the font weight for a text element in JavaScript:

My code here does not work:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('accessibilityButton');
btn.innerHTML = 'Default Text';
btn.innerHTML.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
```

What am I doing wrong?

Please note that I don't want to use any libraries (jQuery et. al.) and am looking for a plain JS solution.

Comment: Thanks Keyser for your edit :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use:

```
btn.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
```

as it's a property of the element itself.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/6ypS8/

Answer (score 5):

You should apply your style directly on your button not on button.innerHTML :

```
btn.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep 'return false' to prevent postback.

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="this.style.fontWeight = 'bold';return false;" >TEXT</button>
```