# Change button text to bold on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make the text of a button become bold when it is clicked on. I have tried using the advice from this question: [How to make a text in font/weight style bold in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673615/how-to-make-a-text-in-font-weight-style-bold-in-javascript)

http://jsfiddle.net/14tjwvnq/

```
function boldButton(){
    $('#btn').style.fontWeight = '700';
}
```

Comment: what should be the behavior when you click it again ? do you need the Bold to be temporary (sec, while holding the mouse down), to taggle on each click , or just to stay bolded after the first click.

Comment: I need it to stay bold after the first click.

Comment: your example gets error "ReferenceError: boldButton is not defined"
as the function is not defined on after the HTML is rendered.
Move the function in the header, or use some selector to assign the ONCLICK to the buttons onLoad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jQuery you need to use [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method:

```
$('#btn').css( 'font-weight', '700' );
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/14tjwvnq/1/)

Answer (score 2):

[YOU MIGHT NOT NEED JQUERY](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)

```
//Inline
<button class="btn" id="btn1" onclick="this.style.fontWeight = 'bold'">Test1</button>
//OR with function
<button class="btn" id="btn2" onclick="boldButton(this)">Test2</button>

<scrypt>
function boldButton(btn){
    btn.style.fontWeight =  '700';
}
</scrypt>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3g3mhcuz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert jquery object to javascript object before setting the property through javascript. also make sure that onclick method is defined :

```
 function boldButton(num){
   $('#btn'+num)[0].style.fontWeight = '700';
 }
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kmc5dqm0/)**